# We need to add new places in google map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We are developing a Google map application.  On the admin side, we should able to create new place in the Google map and have it replicate on the front-end side.

I do not mean marker creation, I am asking about place creation (like street name/village name /business name)

Its possible to do this?

Comment: What is a "place?" You used the word to "clarify" the same word.

Comment: Like street name / village name / business name

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want the information to appear, there are a couple of ways:

1) www.google.com/mapmaker lets you add information to the base Google map. After moderation, it will appear to all users. Mapmaker's only available in certain countries.

2) The Google Places API lets you add places such as establishments and points of interest, and make them available to your own application immediately. They'll also enter the moderation queue and may be added to the base map: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceReports

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we need the option 2 way. But we not understand the api documents, can you help how to do it this.

Comment: Is there a particular part of the documentation you don't understand? Such as one step that's not working for you?

Comment: @MikeJeffrey i am working on how to add places to my map but i still dont understand how it works. I posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116831/how-to-add-places-to-google-map-using-google-api-android . I have done autocomplete using google api and listing of places such as schools, cafe etc.