# How to add places to google map using google api ANDROID

Tags: android, google-maps

I am currently working on how to add places to google map using the google api in my android application. I am able to get the autocomplete of location using the google api and able to get the reverse geocoding working too. I coded the adding of places but when i add the location in my app, the pin was not added. I dont know where is my error. But i guess is my google api url got problem.

**Below is my code:**

```
class addPlaces extends AsyncTask<String, String, PlacesList> {

    @Override
    protected PlacesList doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
            Log.v(LOG_KEY, "Adding Place...");
            GenericUrl reqUrl = new GenericUrl(PLACE_ADD_URL);
            reqUrl.put("key", API_KEY);
            reqUrl.put("sensor", "false");
            Log.v(LOG_KEY, "Adding Place...");
            // reqUrl.put("Host:", "maps.googleapis.com");
            /*
             * reqUrl.put( "Host: maps.googleapis.com",
             * "{\"location\":{\"lat\":" + Double.toString(lat) +
             * ",\"lng\":" + Double.toString(lon) +
             * "},\"accuracy\":50.0,\"name\":\"event\",\"types\":[\"school\"],\"language\":\"en\"}"
             * );
             */
            reqUrl.put(
                    "Host: maps.googleapis.com",
                    "{\"location\":{\"lat\":1.347988,\"lng\":103.936179},\"accuracy\":50.0,\"name\":\"events\",\"types\":[\"school\"],\"language\":\"en\"}");
            Log.v(LOG_KEY, "Requested URL= " + reqUrl);

            HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
            HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory
                    .buildGetRequest(reqUrl);

            Log.v(LOG_KEY, request.execute().parseAsString());
            place = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);

            Log.v(LOG_KEY, "STATUS = " + place.status);
            Log.v(LOG_KEY, "Place Added is = " + place);
            return place;

        } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
            // Log.v(LOG_KEY, e.getResponse().parseAsString());
            Log.v(LOG_KEY, e.getMessage());
            try {
                throw e;
            } catch (HttpResponseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return place;
    }
}
```

**EDITTED**

```
public class AddItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

   private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

   private Context context;

   public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
   }

   public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        this(defaultMarker);
        this.context = context;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView)
   {   

       if (event.getAction() == 1) {
           GeoPoint geopoint = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
               (int) event.getX(),
               (int) event.getY());
           // latitude
           double lat = geopoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
           // longitude
           double lon = geopoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
           //Toast.makeText(context, "Lat: " + lat + ", Lon: "+lon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       return false;
   } 

   @Override
   protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
      return mapOverlays.get(i);
   }

   @Override
   public int size() {
      return mapOverlays.size();
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean onTap(int index) {
     OverlayItem item = mapOverlays.get(index);
     AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context);
     dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
     dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
     dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });
     dialog.show();
     return true;
   }

   public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
      mapOverlays.add(overlay);
   }

   public void populateNow(){
       this.populate();
   }

}
```

**OVERLAY**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_places);

    // Getting intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Users current geo location
    String user_latitude = i.getStringExtra("user_latitude");
    String user_longitude = i.getStringExtra("user_longitude");

    // Nearplaces list
    nearPlaces = (PlacesList) i.getSerializableExtra("near_places");

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    // Geopoint to place on map
    geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(user_latitude) * 1E6),
            (int) (Double.parseDouble(user_longitude) * 1E6));

    // Drawable marker icon
    Drawable drawable_user = this.getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);

    itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable_user, this);

    // Map overlay item
    overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Your Location",
            "That is you!");

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
    itemizedOverlay.populateNow();

    // Drawable marker icon
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_blue);

    itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

    mc = mapView.getController();

    // These values are used to get map boundary area
    // The area where you can see all the markers on screen
    int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int minLong = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int maxLong = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    // check for null in case it is null
    if (nearPlaces.results != null) {
        // loop through all the places
        for (Place place : nearPlaces.results) {
            latitude = place.geometry.location.lat; // latitude
            longitude = place.geometry.location.lng; // longitude

            // Geopoint to place on map
            geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),
                    (int) (longitude * 1E6));

            // Map overlay item
            overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, place.name,
                    place.vicinity);

            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);


            // calculating map boundary area
            minLat  = (int) Math.min( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), minLat );
            minLong = (int) Math.min( geoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), minLong);
            maxLat  = (int) Math.max( geoPoint.getLatitudeE6(), maxLat );
            maxLong = (int) Math.max( geoPoint.getLongitudeE6(), maxLong );
        }
        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

        // showing all overlay items
        itemizedOverlay.populateNow();
    }

    // Adjusting the zoom level so that you can see all the markers on map
    mapView.getController().zoomToSpan(Math.abs( minLat - maxLat ), Math.abs( minLong - maxLong ));

    // Showing the center of the map
    mc.animateTo(new GeoPoint((maxLat + minLat)/2, (maxLong + minLong)/2 ));
    mapView.postInvalidate();

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: try this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/

Comment: this not your code of overlay.. plz show your overlay code

Comment: @CapDroid see my editted part.

Comment: This is not API V3. (tag removed)